# Combobox and autocomplete in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, combobox

i have small problem with autocomplete option in combobox. Everything is working correct, except that i want to work it diffrent :)

When I start typing in combobox, autusuggest working the way i like :

[image: Combo]

But when i first open combobox, and then start typing i get something like that:

[image]

What's more i can't pick item from autosuggest combobox, only from this list under.

AutocompleteMode is SuggestAppend

I'd like to have autosuggest like on the first picture, and in situations like picture 2, this first combobox list should be closed somehow..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it this way:

```
private void comboBox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cbo = (ComboBox)sender;
    cbo.PreviewKeyDown += new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(comboBox_PreviewKeyDown);
}

private void comboBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cbo = (ComboBox)sender;
    cbo.PreviewKeyDown -= comboBox_PreviewKeyDown;
    if (cbo.DroppedDown) cbo.Focus();
}
```

Once the user clicks on the `DropDown` button `PreviewKeyDown` event is attached to that `ComboBox`. When user starts typing, freshly added event is triggered. In that event we check if `ComboBox` is `DroppedDown`, if it is, focus that `ComboBox`. On `ComboBox` focus  `DropDown` disappeares and that's it.

Answer (score 5):

What about using the [DropDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdown.aspx) and [DropDownClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownclosed.aspx) events to disable or change the auto-complete mode?

Comment: Yep, that worked for me. Here's some code that you can use:

`m_cmbNode.DropDown += (sender, e) =>
    m_cmbNode.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;

m_cmbNode.DropDownClosed += (sender, e) =>
    m_cmbNode.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;`

Answer (score 3):

I was having exactly the same problem.
I tried the DropDown and DropDownClosed events to set the AutoCompleteMode property to none and suggest.
In this situation the SelectedIndexChanged event does not get fired after selecting an item with the mouse.
I was using the SelectedValue property in the SelectedIndexChanged event and this property is already changed at the moment the DropDownClosed event is triggered.
In my case I simply called the SelectedIndexChanged method from the DropDownClosed event to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Implement event on ComboBox KeyDown. It should look like this.

```
void cmbExample_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as ComboBox).DroppedDown)
            (sender as ComboBox).DroppedDown = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the other possible values for `AutoCompleteMode`, which are `Append`, `None`, and `Suggest`? I think that what you are looking for is `Suggest` instead of `AppendSuggest`.

Here is some [downloadable sample code](http://www.visualwebgui.com/Developers/KB/tabid/654/article/combobox_autocomplete_sample/Default.aspx) illustrating the different modes, if you need it.

Comment: I've tried them. Append is to show rest of the value, and suggest is this new combobox window. I'd like to have this new combobox with suggest mode. But then this first list should be closed..

Answer (score 2):

I also found the default UI implementation distracting as the two dropdowns fight for mouse control.

You want to hide the dropdown list when autocomplete suggestions are shown.  There is a windows message that the combobox makes before showing the autocomplete suggestions.  I chose to collapse the droplist in response to this message.  It requires a small override of the combobox to achieve this:

```
Public Class Combobox2
    Inherits ComboBox

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If m.Msg = 135 AndAlso DroppedDown Then 'WM_GETDLGCODE
            DroppedDown = False
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void cmbExample_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  cmbExample.DroppedDown = false;
}
```