# on-the-fly search algorithm in listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, search

So, I have a listbox with x number of items. On top of the listbox I have a TextBox (this is the search field). I try do develop an algorithm that removes items from the listbox, if it doesn't contain the searchword (variable keyword in the code). This is supposed to happen for each key the user types (on-the-fly). So, the code:

```
   private void _keywordTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string keyword = _keywordTextBox.Text;

        if (keyword == searchtext || isSpace) // do nothing if space is typed - searchtext is a templatetext in the textbox ("type here to search...")
            return; // ignore
        else if (keyword == "")
        {
            listBox.Items.Clear();

            foreach (string s in originalList)
                listBox.Items.Add(s);
        }
        else
        {
            List<string> selection = new List<string>();

            foreach (string s in originalList) // originalList is the listbox at startup
                selection.Add(s);

            listBox.BeginUpdate();
            string[] keywordSplit = keyword.Split(' ');

            try
            {
                for (int i = originalList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    string[] selectionSplit = selection[i].Split(' ');

                    int l = 0; // number of hits

                    for (int j = 0; j < selectionSplit.Length; j++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < keywordSplit.Length; k++)
                        {
                            if (selectionSplit[j].ToLower().Contains(keywordSplit[k].ToLower()))
                            {
                                l++;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (l < keywordSplit.Length) // Not hit on all keywords
                        selection.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                listBox.Items.Clear();

                foreach (string s in selection) // Add selection in listbox
                    listBox.Items.Add(s);

                if (listBox.Items.Count > 0)
                    listBox.SetSelected(0, true); // Select first item in listbox

                listBox.EndUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is hard to describe, other than it doesn't work as intended. The behavour is, as far as I can see, sporadic.

If I search for "ck flow", I should get a hit for stackoverflow. More importantly, it should also work if I deletes chars (delete key of backspace). Anybody?

Edit: more details:

The listbox should shrink and grow on each keystroke, based on what the user searches for. The listbox should keep every item that matches the keyword typed in by the user, and filter away that doesn't match.

Comment: I guess the functionality you are trying to achieve is provide by Microsoft's `ComboBox` with `AutoComplete` feature see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243611/combobox-and-autocomplete-in-c-sharp

Comment: Please explain the code's intended purpose in more detail. Which elements should be displayed, or filtered? Maybe give some more examples.

Comment: @yogi No :) It only searched the beginning of the string, not in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could try to work out a Regular Expression:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string keyword = textBox1.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword.Trim()))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(_originalList.ToArray());
    }
    else
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(GetRegexPatternFromKeyword(keyword));
        List<string> selection =
            _originalList.Where(s => regex.IsMatch(s)).ToList();
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(selection.ToArray());
    }
}

private static string GetRegexPatternFromKeyword(string keyword)
{
    string[] words =
        keyword.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(word => "(?=.*" + word.Replace(")", @"\)") + ")").ToArray();
    return string.Join("", words);
}
```

**disclaimer**: there could be some cases where an input would 'destroy' the regex pattern

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks. But isn't regex slow to use? Not that it matters in my case, since I have maximum 100 items.

Comment: With 100 items, I wouldn't worry to much indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code increases l too often. For instance;

the text 'aaa aaa aaa' with searchword 'aaa bbb' will give an l of 3 because every time you find 'aaa' you increase l. So this will be a match even though 'bbb' is never found.

You can fix this (among others) by deleting found parts of keywordsplit and recreating keywordsplit anew before every search of a new selectionline.

```
l++;
break;
```

becomes

```
l++
keywordSplit.RemoveAt[k];
break;
```

and move

```
string[] keywordSplit = keyword.Split(' ');
```

to just before you start the k loop

Altough I feel there might be better ways to achieve what you want with a bit cleaner and faster code it should work.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. But at this point I just want it to work so I can see the logic. Afterwords I can try to optimize it. I will test your changes now. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't work. keywordSplit is an array, so it can't remove items like that.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. @IvoTops helped me in the right direction. Just loop trough all the keyword first, and then the selections.

```
                for (int j = 0; j < keywordSplit.Length; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < selectionSplit.Length; k++)
                    {
                        if (selectionSplit[k].ToLower().Contains(keywordSplit[j].ToLower()))
                        {
                            l++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Seems to work ok now.