# How to search listbox using the same criteria as like "%%" in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

How to search ListBox using the same criteria as like "%%" in sql
for example if the list contains the following items {cat , dog , cat with ring,dog with bone}
and entered "with" in the textbox. i need to filter this listbox to only have records containig the word "with" ( i.e {cat with ring,dog with bone}).

so far i can search and select the item starting with the input string using this code ..

```
    private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = lst.FindString(this.txtSearch.Text);
        if (0 <= index)
        {
            lst.SelectedIndex = index;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how is your list box being populated? is it bound to a data source? Have you considered using `string.Contains` to filter it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068154/on-the-fly-search-algorithm-in-listbox

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
string searchTerm = this.txtSearch.Text;
var items = lst.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(t=>t.Value.Contains(searchTerm));
```

`items` will then contain all ListItems that have a `Value` that contains your search term.